# Calculating correlation and covariance in MySQL

Tags: data, data-science-model, sql

I am new to data science taking my first course in Data analysis.  I am trying to figure out where to start with a problem solving the correlation and covariance with my sql.

```
#this is the table I'm using
mysql> SELECT surfacearea, population FROM country LIMIT 5;
+-------------+------------+
| surfacearea | population |
+-------------+------------+
|      193.00 |     103000 |
|   652090.00 |   22720000 |
|  1246700.00 |   12878000 |
|       96.00 |       8000 |
|    28748.00 |    3401200 |
+-------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

# this is my formula

WITH Cov(x,y) AS
(SELECT sum((x - avgx)*(y - avgy)) /
       (count -1 * stdev(x)*stdev(y)) as covxy
 FROM R)
SELECT covxy/stddev(x)*stddev(y) as xycorrelation
FROM R, Cov
```

Where in the heck am I supposed to select the table from to get my x and y values?

So far here is what I have but it's erring out.  Error code 1064 syntax error:

```
    SELECT avg(surfacearea)AS Xavg, avg(population) AS Yavg 
(SELECT Xavg * Yavg / COUNT(population) * stddev(Xavg) * stdev(Yavg) AS covxy FROM country)
SELECT covxy / stddev(surfacearea)*stddev(population) as xycorrelation
FROM country;
```

Another attempt

```
WITH country(surfacearea,population) AS
(SELECT sum(surfacearea - avg(surfacearea))*(population - avg(population)) /
((COUNT(*) -1) * stdev(surfacearea)*stdev(population)) as covxy FROM country)
SELECT covxy / (stddev(surfacearea)*stddev(population)) as xycorrelation
FROM country;
```

Comment: This deserves to be asked on Stackoverflow maybe!

Comment: I thought this would be the best place since it deals with data science.  Stack is very weird, they kick you off and limit your questions.

Comment: So far here is what I have but it's erring out.  Error code 1064 syntax error:  Just edited original question

Comment: Actually I am not that comfortable with SQL and have not seen anyone asking and reply to SQL based question, that's why! Maybe someone might respond

Comment: Here is a possible answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457645/mysql-math-is-it-possible-to-calculate-a-correlation-in-a-query